# Отправить html почту с помощью python smtplib и email.mime.multipart

Tags: python, linux, email, format

func:

```
def send_mail(self, recipients):
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
sender = 'my@mail'
msg['Subject'] = "My subj"
msg['From'] = sender
recipients = recipients.split(",")
# msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients.split(",")) Почему, кстати, так не работает?
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

text = "Hi there! My table:"
html = "Что тут написать, чтоб отправить html /tmp/report.html"
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
try:
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('my.mail.srv')
    mail.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()
    print "Successfully sent email"

except Exception as err:
    print "Error: unable to send email: %s" % err
```

HTML via /tmp/report.html :

```
<html>
<body>
<br></br>
<FONT size=4><B>Hello!</B></FONT>
<br></br>
<table border=1>
 <tr>
   <td><B>ROW1</B></td>
   <td><B>ROW2</B></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <td>ololo</td>
     <td>tralala</td>
 </tr>


 </table>
      <BR />
      <FONT size=4><B> Bye! </B></FONT><BR>
      </B></FONT><BR />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Несколько вопросов:

1. Как заставить отсылать этот html чтоб нарисовать эту таблицу в письме прям?
2. Как-то можно формировать его переменной? Сейчас я сначала делаю файл, потом скрипт заполняет его кучей ololo и tralala , затем я приписываю туда окончание и мне надо его отсылать. Можно это делать не в файле, а в переменной? Так наверно будет проще...
3. Там в комменте написано...

**Вопрос 1 решился так:**

```html
 def send_mail(self, recipients):
  import smtplib
  from email.mime.text import MIMEText
  from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

  msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  sender = 'my@mail'
  msg['Subject'] = "My subj"
  msg['From'] = sender
  recipients = recipients.split(",")
  # msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients.split(",")) Почему, кстати, так не работает?
  msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

  text = "Hi there! My table:"
  html = open('/tmp/report.html', 'r').read()
  part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
  part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
  msg.attach(part1)
  msg.attach(part2)
  try:
   mail = smtplib.SMTP('my.mail.srv')
   mail.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
   mail.quit()
   print "Successfully sent email"

  except Exception as err:
   print "Error: unable to send email: %s" % err
```

**Остальные вопросы ещё актуальны!**

Comment: Дайте текст ошибки по третьему.

Comment: @mkkik прикол в том, что ошибки нет. Вот если ты посылаешь ему ['a@b.c', 'x@z.y'] (То есть my_class().send_mail('a@b.c, x@z.y') - то письмо приходит только первому. Формат и type в обоих случаях одинаковый. Я пробовал и с помощью list и с str и в "" закрывал - не катит. Вот катит почему-то только если сначала сделать сплит, и только потом джойн, - тогда всем получателям отправляет. Не могу понять почему :(

Comment: 1. `['a@b.c', 'x@z.y']` и 'a@b.c, x@z.y' не одно и то же. 2. `mail.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())` - в этой строке вы отправляете исходную строку `recipients` - не тут ли ошибка?

Comment: Вы не поняли. И сейчас, и если раскоментить то что там закоменчено - print и type msg['To'] выводят одно и то же. Поэтому я не могу понять, в чём отличие-то... P.S. Если интересно, пример взял отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib

Comment: В том, что сейчас строка `recipients` изменяется, а если делать так, как в закомментированной строке, она не изменяется.

Comment: Хмм, кажется я начинаю потихоньку понимать что в письмо ресипиенты берутся из двух мест: из recipients и из msg['To'] ... http://cs6.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2014-09_3/14107482488406.jpg

Comment: 1- старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос (чтобы ваш вопрос мог ещё кому-нибудь пригодится) -- вы можете несколько разных вопросов задать 2- не помещайте ваше решение/ответ в вопрос, публикуйте ответ как ответ. 3- вот [пример кода отправки почты и с html и с картинкой и с MIMEMultipart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20485764/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос:

```
    def send_mail(self, recipients):
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    sender = 'my@mail'
    msg['Subject'] = "My subj"
    msg['From'] = sender
    recipients = recipients.split(",")
    # msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients.split(",")) Почему, кстати, так не работает?
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

    text = "Hi there! My table:"
    html = open('/tmp/report.html', 'r').read()
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    try:
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('my.mail.srv')
        mail.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()
        print "Successfully sent email"

    except Exception as err:
        print "Error: unable to send email: %s" % err
```

остальные актуальны...

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/80772)

Comment: поправил. Так лучше?

Comment: Правку нужно вносить в вопрос, а не в ответ. Напишите например: 1 вопрос решился так: и добавьте код в свернутом виде (это делается с помощью вставки фрагмента кода, и снизу установка галочки `скрывать`)

Comment: это делается с помощью вставки фрагмента кода, и снизу установка галочки скрывать - я так не умею :(

Comment: В панели управления сообщением есть: жирный текст, наклонный текст, вставка ссылки, цитата, код, картинка, **фрагмент кода**, ...списки.

Comment: Поправил. Сейчас правильно? P.S. Это реально слишком сложно для меня)))

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев: ответы (даже неполные) должны в ответах располагаться, а не в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs есть правила на этот случай, что ответ должен быть только полным, частичный ответ должен быть добавлен в вопрос, в тревогах есть такой пункт

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев можете ссылку на правила и обсуждение где эти правила приняли привести? Потому что я мог бы понять предложение  разбить текущий вопрос  на несколько, но не могу понять какая польза от ответа в тексте вопроса, где за него нельзя голосовать, комментировать отдельно от самого вопроса итд.